# T-SQL Table Getting Right Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like that. (there are more records)

[image]

Here is the question. How can I get the first 20 customers having money (amount) between 9000 and 24000 in same bank branch (BranchID), multiple same currency accounts (not only one).

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select distinct top 20 
  yt.CustomerId
from [$your_table] yt
group by yt.CustomerId, yt.BranchId, yt.Currency
having count(*)>1
  and sum(yt.amount) between 9000 and 24000
```

The `count(*)>1` catchs those customers with the same branch and currency more than once. Then, for the sum of the amounts (`sum(yt.amount)`) it gets just those between 9000 and 24000.

Finally, because the same customer could have more than one record (same branch and two different currencys several times - or even several branches), we get the `distinct top 20 CustomerId`.

Comment: Happy to help @codeigniter. Anyway... I understand it's an exercise and not  in production environment. There is no point filtering "any" currency between 9000 and 24000.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use `TOP` for this.

As in:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
FROM TABLE
WHERE filter condition...
```

Comment: My question is not just that